# Remove Rows that contain 0

Tags: r

I am trying to remove all rows, which contain at least one 0.
I found this code online:

```
dataZ <- data[apply(data, 1, function(row) all(row !=0 )), ]
```

and this code:

```
dataZ <- data[ !rowSums(data[,colnames(df)[(3:ncol(data))]]==0)>=1, ]
```

It does not work, my table remains the same:

```
Date        H1 H2 H3 H4 H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16 H17  H18 H19 H20 H21 H22 
2021-07-05   0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 970 930  942 808 590 441 361 
2021-07-06  60 41 22 13 47 173 487 813 818 762 832 825 778 804 890 881   0  881 888 616 498 318 
2021-07-07 130 42 22 21 43 178 494 803 785 794 790 839 844 835 870 890 866 1031 811 609 496 374
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks#1

Comment: Why do you have two names for the dataframe? (data and df)? I think it's a typo

Answer (score 1):

**1)** When acting on a data frame `apply` first converts it to a matrix and if `Date` is character as in the reproducible data shown in the Note at the end (or has Date class) then that will result in a character matrix for which every element gives FALSE when compared to a numeric 0.  To prevent this exclude the first column so that when it converts to matrix it converts the data frame to a numeric matrix.

```
data[apply(data[-1], 1, function(row) all(row != 0 )), ]
```

or slightly shorter:

```
data[apply(data[-1] != 0, 1, all), ]
```

This also works because data != 0 is a logical matrix and Date != 0 is always TRUE but it is a bit tricky so you might prefer the one above.

```
data[apply(data != 0, 1, all), ]
```

**2)** In the second attempt in the question it uses `df` which is not defined.  Use this:

```
data[ !rowSums(data[-1] == 0) > 0, ]
```

or this for the same reason that we were able to remove -1 above.

```
data[ !rowSums(data == 0) > 0, ]
```

or even

```
data[ !rowSums(data == 0), ]
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Date        H1 H2 H3 H4 H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16 H17  H18 H19 H20 H21 H22 
2021-07-05   0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 970 930  942 808 590 441 361 
2021-07-06  60 41 22 13 47 173 487 813 818 762 832 825 778 804 890 881   0  881 888 616 498 318 
2021-07-07 130 42 22 21 43 178 494 803 785 794 790 839 844 835 870 890 866 1031 811 609 496 374"
data <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

A `tidyverse` solution: you first reshape your data to a long format, then you only keep rows with a `value` row that is different from `0`, and then you reshape back to a wide format, if you must.

```r
library(tidyr)
data |>
  pivot_longer(-Date) |>
  subset(value != 0) |> 
  pivot_wider()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first solution you posted is indeed working! Look at this example:

```
data <- data.frame(H1 = c(0,1,2), H2 = c(1,10,3), H3 = c(1,3,40))

dataZ <- data[apply(data, 1, function(row) all(row != 0)),]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  filter(!if_any(everything(), ~.x == 0))
```

Or:

```
df %>% 
  filter(if_all(everything(), ~.x != 0))

        Date  H1 H2 H3 H4 H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16 H17  H18 H19 H20 H21 H22
1 2021-07-07 130 42 22 21 43 178 494 803 785 794 790 839 844 835 870 890 866 1031 811 609 496 374
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to approach this problem is to find out the *locations* of all zeros in the data frame, and then identify the row numbers of the locations, and then subset the data frame by removing those rows.

Here is a step-by-step example how to do that in base-R by using the data you provided in the question.

1. Reproducing your data

```
mydf <- read.table(text = "Date        H1 H2 H3 H4 H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16 H17  H18 H19 H20 H21 H22 
2021-07-05   0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 970 930  942 808 590 441 361 
2021-07-06  60 41 22 13 47 173 487 813 818 762 832 825 778 804 890 881   0  881 888 616 498 318 
2021-07-07 130 42 22 21 43 178 494 803 785 794 790 839 844 835 870 890 866 1031 811 609 496 374", header = TRUE)

mydf
# Date  H1 H2 H3 H4 H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16 H17  H18 H19 H20 H21 H22
# 1 2021-07-05   0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 970 930  942 808 590 441 361
# 2 2021-07-06  60 41 22 13 47 173 487 813 818 762 832 825 778 804 890 881   0  881 888 616 498 318
# 3 2021-07-07 130 42 22 21 43 178 494 803 785 794 790 839 844 835 870 890 866 1031 811 609 496 374
```

2. Finding out the locations of all zeros

```
which(mydf == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
# [1,]   1   2
# [2,]   1   3
# [3,]   1   4
# [4,]   1   5
# [5,]   1   6
# [6,]   1   7
# [7,]   1   8
# [8,]   1   9
# [9,]   1  10
# [10,]   1  11
# [11,]   1  12
# [12,]   1  13
# [13,]   1  14
# [14,]   1  15
# [15,]   1  16
# [16,]   2  18
```

From this step we got many duplicated number of rows. We need only the unique number of rows:

3. Get the unique number of rows in which zeros are found.

```
rows_with_zeros <-  unique(which(mydf == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)[,"row"])
rows_with_zeros
# [1] 1 2
```

4. Subset the data frame by excluding the rows with zeros. We can use `-` sign.

```
mydf[-rows_with_zeros,]
# Date  H1 H2 H3 H4 H5  H6  H7  H8  H9 H10 H11 H12 H13 H14 H15 H16 H17  H18 H19 H20 H21 H22
# 3 2021-07-07 130 42 22 21 43 178 494 803 785 794 790 839 844 835 870 890 866 1031 811 609 496 374
```